# How to add a polymorphic association to an existing model from a Gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Suppose I have included a gem called `acts_as_locatable` in my project with an `ActsAsLocatable::Location` class defined within it. I want to add a polymorphic `:subject` association to this class, which could be accomplished by simply editing the class in the gem to add the association, like this:

```
module ActsAsLocatable

  class Location < ::ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :subject, polymorphic: true

    ...

  end

end
```

But this is a bad idea since I don't want to have to maintain this change with each update of the gem. Forking the Gem and modifying the fork also suffers from this same problem.

How can I extend, decorate or otherwise augment this class to add a polymorphic `:subject` association without editing the model file in the gem, while leaving the rest of the functionality of the gem undisturbed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more research about monkey patching, it seems that one solution is to add an initializer (such as `<root>/config/initializers/acts_as_locatable.rb`):

```
ActsAsLocatable::Location.class_eval do
  belongs_to      :subject,           polymorphic: true
end
```

Is this the best option?